# Java Mail - Answer Mail, create reply message with the old content

Tags: java, api, email

Is there a **function** which create the reply message automatically.
As example I would like to create the history from all emails which have been sent. So if I press the reply button, this should be generated automatically:

```
    From: Name Name <test@mail.com> 
Sent: Thursday, August 30, 2018 10:08 AM
To: Test Test <test2@mail.com>; Test2 Test2 <test2@mail.com>
Subject: TestSubject
Importance: High 
<and here all content from previous emails....>
```

Is this possible or should I create this on my own?
Is there also a different for formatting if I use plain/text or html/text?
How can I create than a breakline in plain/text?

Maybe someone creates already this or it´s already included in a API?
Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried to find a solution on it? E.g. [this](https://codesjava.com/javamail-api-replying-emails) was in the first or the second google page...